# Use offline cppreference for context help in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Here are [cppreference archives for offline viewing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives)

I would like to see C++ documentation from cppreference.com in VS Code instead of whatever is there in the documentation comments of the currently selected installation of standard library headers (as shown below).

[image]

Is there a simple way to make VS Code and cppreference.com friends?

Comment: Damn -- Why didn't MS think about that.... That's a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension (but dependending on your experience doing that, I wouldn't really call that "simple").

Or you could just use one that someone else wrote. At the time of this writing, there are two extensions on the Visual Studio Marketplace that show up when searching "cppreference" <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with these extensions)</sub></sup>:

- [`Guyutongxue.cpp-reference`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Guyutongxue.cpp-reference)

  Basically allows you to use an action on a standard symbol and opens the webpage in a new side window.
- [`FederAndInk.cpp-reference-and-documentation`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FederAndInk.cpp-reference-and-documentation)

  A fork of [`kunalg.library-documentation-cpp`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kunalg.library-documentation-cpp)

I'm not sure if these extensions function offline though.